# Regex for url route with query string

Tags: regex, url-routing

I am having hard time learning regex and honestly I have no time at the moment. 
I am looking for a regex expression that would match url route with query string

What I need is regex to match **population?filter=nation** of course where nation can be any string.

Based on my current regex knowledge I have also tried with regex expression `/^population\/(?P<filterval>\d+)\/filter$/` to match **population/nation/filter** but this does not work.

Any suggestion and help is welcome.

Comment: Perhaps, `^\/?population(?:\/|\?filter=)(?P<filterval>[^\/]+)(?:\/filter\/?)?$` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI8zP9/1))?

Comment: Wait ... which expression do you want to match? the first or the second one?

Comment: @Serv Ideally first second one was attempt based on my regex knowledge.

Comment: Can `nation` values contain characters like `-`? Like in "Great-Britain" or "New-Zealand" just for the sake of being there. Not being gramatically correct and is this the complete querystring or does something else follow? (filter=nation&foo=bar) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does match only your first query string format:

```
population\?filter=[\w]+[-_]?[\w]+
```

Addiotionally it allows for `-` and `_` as bindings between words. If you know, that your string ends right there, you can also add an `$` to the end to mark it so.

If you know that the nation is only alphabetical characters, yu can use the simplified version:

```
 population\?filter=[\w]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG3gN5/1)

Comment: I had to add forward slashes at the beginning and end '/population\?filter=[\w]+[-_]?[\w]+/' because it reported "Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in ..." Beside that this was very helpful! Thanks!